# Is it best way to develop react in nestjs by bundling the react code to a single file and used in nestjs?

Tags: reactjs, nestjs

I'm new to nestjs and want to develop a simple server which serves react pages.

My current process is:

1. create a client directory for an independent react frontend project, and use some bundlers to build a single js for nestjs
2. In server directory which is for nestjs, start nestjs rendering the index.html in public directory with the bundle file

Which is working but clumsy， is there any easier way to develop react in nestjs, e.g. ignore the bundling step and also support react hot-loading?

A small demo repo for my idea:

https://github.com/freewind-demos/typescript-nestjs-react-demo